# Compare multiple file name with the prefix of name in same directory

Tags: python, scripting

I have multiple  .png and .json file in same directory . And I want to check where the files available in the directory are of same name or not like a.png & a.json, b.png & b.json

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
import os

_, _ ,files = os.walk('.').next()
json = [f[:-5] for f in files if f.endswith('.json')]
png  = [f[:-4] for f in files if f.endswith('.png')]

json_only = set(json) - set(png)
png_only = set(png) - set(json)

json_and_png = set(json) & set(png)

... etc...
```

Comment: Is it for n no of files ?

Comment: @ritd where did you find `n` in my answer ?

Comment: actually im just a beginner in python so just little bit confused.Also how to import directory in above code from my computer where all the files are exists.

Comment: @ritd an argument for the `os.walk()` function tells the directory name, right now it's '.' -- the current directory

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/untitled/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    files = os.walk('.').next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: @ritd apparently you're using python3, try `next(os.walk('.'))`

Comment: Thank you very much. Code ran without any error. But didnt showed any output !!!                   
                 
C:\Users\xyz\PycharmProjects\untitled\HelloWorld\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/untitled/app.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @ritd you should specify the correct folder with the .json and .png files

Comment: I think I did that

Comment: import os

parent_dir = r"E:\PackageTesting\viking_towers\desktop\png\animation"
_, _ ,files = next(os.walk('.'))
json = [f[:-5] for f in files if f.endswith('.json')]
png = [f[:-4] for f in files if f.endswith('.png')]

json_only = set(json) - set(png)
png_only = set(png) - set(json)

json_and_png = set(json) & set(png)

Answer (score 0):

@lenik is on the right track, I believe using sets is the easiest way to get what you want. Here's a complete and tested solution using the pathlib module that lists any png/json files that do not have a matching pair in the provided folder and all sub-folders:

```py
def get_unpaired_files(directory: str) -> []:
    dir_path = Path(directory).resolve()
    json_files = get_files_without_extension(dir_path, pattern='*.json')
    png_files = get_files_without_extension(dir_path, pattern='*.png')
    return [str(f) for f in set(json_files) ^ set(png_files)]

def get_files_without_extension(dir_path: Path, pattern: str) -> []:
    return [f.with_suffix('') for f in dir_path.rglob(pattern)]
```

Usage:

```py
unpaired_files = get_unpaired_files(r'E:\abc')

if unpaired_files :
    print('Unpaired file paths were found:')
    print('\n'.join(unpaired_files))
```

Comment: In same script how can we use path as relative path like whichever folder is available under E:\abc\"whichever folder".Because in next iteration there would be another folder with another name with same conditions.Is it possible?

Comment: That's actually an easy fix. The pathlib library has a method called `resolve()` that converts a relative path to absolute. So you can call `get_unpaired_files('./folder1')` and 
`get_unpaired_files('./folder2')` from `E:\abc` and it will scan each of those folders. If you want to scan all sub-folders in `E:\abc` just call `get_unpaired_files('.')` from that folder. I edited the reply to fix this. If this response answered your question, please up-vote and select as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: edited reply is traversing all subfolders and printing the .json & .png which matched to the game prefix name. I am posting my edited script below. Is there any way to make any minor change in that to get desired result.

Comment: @winx I added the iteration through sub-folders in my reply to your question here: stackoverflow.com/a/62325432/5752730 . I'm not sure why you posted code from that question here, but I hope this answers your question. If it does, please up-vote and select as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
print("TEST CASE::NAMING CONVENTIONS SHOULD BE START WITH GAME PREFIX ")
def get_invalid_files_from(directory: str) -> []:
    dir_path = Path(r"E:\abc\\xyz")
    parent_folder = dir_path.stem
    files = dir_path.rglob('*')
    return [str(f) for f in files if is_file_invalid(f, prefix=parent_folder)]

def is_file_invalid(file: Path, prefix: str) -> bool:
    return file.suffix.lower() in ['.png', '.json'] and not file.name.startswith(prefix)
testcase = True
invalid_files = get_invalid_files_from(r'E:\abc\\xyz')
#assert not invalid_files, 'Invalid file paths:\n' + '\n'.join(invalid_files)

if invalid_files :
    testcase = False
    print(r'Below given File found with invalid prefix:')
    print('\n'.join(invalid_files))
if not testcase:
    print("test case failed ")
else:
    print("Test Case Passed ")
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to combine answers from 2 stackoverflow questions, is that correct? The behavior you're looking for is still not clear. Please provide very clear examples of specific filenames and folders, with the exact expected printout.

Comment: @DV82XL Above script print those .json & .png files which doesn't match with folder name(xyz) prefix and print the other statements accordingly. Now what I want that Instead of defining "xyz" in full path, it traverse the available folder in "abc" because "xyz" is dynamic package folder and it changes at every iteration. So can we use resolve() with the dir_path or is there any other way to do that.

Comment: like we use ..\ to move up in the directory so what can we use to move down after E:\abc\ by using any kind of practice or do we need to change the code @DV82XL

Comment: I think I understand your problem... you want to call the script from E:\abc\xyz, but you don't know the name of xyz in advance. So you can call the script from E:\abc, which will traverse xyz, but it will use "abc" as the base folder name. You want to use "xyz" as the base folder name. Is that correct? Can you tell me... is "xyz" the only sub-folder in E:\abc ? That would simplify the solution a bit.

Comment: xyz would be only sub-folder and in next iteration sub-folder can be any other name. Basically this is a package testing approach. We will have different package name every-time. @DV82XL

Comment: Check out my comments to my own answer. I believe I found a decent solution. Try it out and let me know if this works.

Comment: No problem is still same. it is printing all the json and png files which have same suffix name. I want those files which don't have same suffix. I manually changed the suffix of some json and png to check if script is working or not. It is not @DV82XL

Comment: Fixed That.. That was some python 3 mistake. Thanq very much. You are the man :-) @DV82XL

Comment: Great, glad to hear you finally fixed your problem! Please upvote my answers in this post and your other post (white up arrow on left) and click the green check box on left to mark them as the correct answer.

Comment: @DV82XL man need your help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027378/file-confirmation-from-a-document-using-python/63027653#63027653