# verify if files(.png, .json) available in a directory start with the directory name

Tags: python

Suppose if path is "E:\vito" then all the .PNG & .JSON files available in the directory and sub-directory start with the directory_prefix(vito) name. Like vito_1.json & vito_1.png.... What could be python script for that.Can anybody help me with it please ?

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? You can use the [built-in `os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for this.

Comment: @theletz if condition fulfilled then testcase passed & if not then print the .json & .png name which doesn't contain folder name as prefix

Comment: Please update the question itself to clarify what you're actually looking for with an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the pathlib module. The function below returns any png or json files that are not prefixed with the directory name. If the returned list is not empty, assert and print invalid filenames. If the returned list is empty, then all filenames are valid.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_invalid_files_from(directory: Path) -> []:
    dir_path = directory.resolve()
    parent_folder = dir_path.stem
    files = dir_path.rglob('*')
    return [str(f) for f in files if is_file_invalid(f, prefix=parent_folder)]

def is_file_invalid(file: Path, prefix: str) -> bool:
    return file.suffix.lower() in ['.png', '.json'] and not file.name.startswith(prefix)
```

Usage:

```py
root_dir = Path(r'C:\abc')
sub_dirs = [f for f in root_dir.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]

# Loop through all sub-directories and evaluate each with their own base folder
for target_dir in sub_dirs:
    invalid_files = get_invalid_files_from(target_dir)

    if invalid_files:
        print('Test failed! Invalid file paths:')
        print('\n'.join(invalid_files))
    else:
        print('Test passed')
```

Comment: This code is working fine & showing the invalid files in main directory "E:\abc\vito" but this is not able to traverse the sub-directories inside main directory "E:\abc\vito". Although I put  ['**\*.png', '**\*.json'] on the place of  ['.png', '.json']. Also it does not publish that in which directory the mismatched png & json exist.

Comment: @winx To get the full path, just need to call f.absolute() instead of f.name. To recursively traverse the dir, need to use glob() instead of iterdir(). I made the changes in the answer.

Comment: Turns out you don't even need to call f.absolute()... just str(f) is enough to get the full absolute path.

Comment: @winx If this response answered your question, please up-vote and select as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use an `assert`? An if statement would still print the invalid files without raising an error.

Comment: @bisen2 The author mentioned a "testcase" in a comment to the question. Test cases assert. You can do anything with the function's output you want. I updated the answer with a print. Great suggestion.

Comment: @winx I added iteration through sub-folders with different base folder names here. I hope this solves your question. If it does, please up-vote and select as correct answer. If you have additional questions, please post new stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
import os

PATH = 'E:/vito'

root, _, files = os.walk(PATH).next()  # or next(os.walk(...)) for python3
folder = os.path.split(root)
start_with_folder_name = [f for f in files if f.startswith(folder)]
```

Comment: File "C:/Users/rdwivedi/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 7
    start_with_folder_name = [f in files if f.startswith(folder)]
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @winx sorry, typo, fixed, try again

Comment: This solution doesn't address png or json file types as specified in the question

Comment: @winx you may want to check this question about the json/png file pairs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058742/compare-multiple-file-name-with-the-prefix-of-name-in-same-directory/62058793#62058793

Comment: @DV82XL already addressed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058742/compare-multiple-file-name-with-the-prefix-of-name-in-same-directory/62058793#62058793

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to find all .PNG & .JSON files in your directory and its subdirectories:

```
import os

valid_files = []
for folder, _, files in os.walk(r"E:\vito"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(folder, file)
        if (filepath.endswith(".png") or filepath.endswith(".json")) and filepath.startswith("vito"):
            valid_files.append(filepath)
```

Comment: I want to check if .png & .json contain the prefix "vito"

Comment: code runs successfully but I manually change a files prefix from vito.png to a.png but it didn't print the name of mismatched png file. Same goes with vito.json to.

Comment: This solution only creates a list of valid filenames. It does not identify whether or not there are any invalid png/json filenames as specified in the question (see comments)

Comment: @DV82XL can you help me with this also please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532221