# list out the images of higher resolution using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to write a python script which will walk through a directory and traverse the all sub directories and if any jpg or png image has higher resolution than 2048*2048 then print out the name of those images. I am not able to traverse the sub-directories. Can anyone plz look into the code

```
import os
import matplotlib.image as plt

root_path = 'E:\newfolder'
img_list = os.listdir(root_path)

for img_name in img_list:

    if img_name.endswith(('.png', '.jpg')):
        img = plt.imread(root_path+'/'+img_name)

        if img.shape[0] > 2048 and img.shape[1] > 2048:
            print(root_path, img_name)
```

Comment: change your root paths `'\'` with `'/'`.

Comment: @BhargavDesai tried..didnt worked

Comment: Your current root_path has a newline character `'\n'`. When you use `'\'` you should prefix the string with `r` (raw string), like this: `root_path = r'E:\newfolder'`

Comment: Also, os.listdir() will return a list of filenames and sub-directories without the full path. So you can't simply append them to root_path, since that doesn't include the sub-directory they came from. I suggest using `pathlib.rglob` or `os.walk` as proposed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete and tested solution that is similar to answers by @Paul and @BrainCity. You'll see that I prefer using small, clear functions, since these encourage reusable code.

You can do the image processing using matplotlib as you do in your question, but you need to install `Pillow` in order to handle .JPG images, since matplotlib only supports PNG natively. I prefer using Pillow directly unless you're already using matplotlib for other stuff.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

def print_high_res_images(directory: str):
    root_path = Path(directory).resolve()
    high_res_images = get_high_res_images(root_path)

    if high_res_images:
        print('High resolution images:')
        for file_path in high_res_images:
            print(file_path)

def get_high_res_images(root_path: Path) -> []:
    return [path for path in root_path.rglob("*.*") if is_high_res_image(path)]

def is_high_res_image(file_path: Path) -> bool:
    if is_image(file_path):
        image = Image.open(file_path)
        width, height = image.size
        return width > 2048 and height > 2048

    return False

def is_image(file: Path) -> bool:
    return file.suffix.lower() in ['.png', '.jpg']

# Test our new function:
print_high_res_images(r'E:\newfolder')
```

Comment: @winx If this answers your question please up-vote (white up arrow) and select it as the correct answer (green check mark). Thanks!

Comment: Thanx buddy. You are the savior :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.5+, you can use the `pathlib` module, and then use a recursive glob pattern to find all files in all subdirectories. Then, you filter the paths and retain only those whose suffix is `.png` or `.jpg`:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in [path for path in Path("dir/to/images").rglob("*.*") if path.suffix.lower() in (".png", ".jpg")]:
    # image = Image(path)
    # if image dimensions greater than 2048 x 2048:
    #     print(path)
```

`print(path)` will print out the entire absolute path of the current image, but if you just want to print out the name, you can `print(path.name)`, which will include the suffix (file extension). If you just want the name of the file without the extension, you can `print(path.stem)`.

Comment: @winx Yes, the body of the for-loop is just pseudo-code. You'll have to implement that part on your own.

Answer (score 1):

**crawl subdirectory using os.walk**

```
import os
import pathlib
from PIL import Image

def crawlImages(directory):
    allowedExtensions = ['.jpg', '.png']
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for f in files:
            if pathlib.Path(f).suffix in allowedExtensions:
                fileName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, f))
                image = Image.open(fileName)
                width, height = image.size

                # checking minimum image width and height
                if width > 2400 and height > 2400:
                    print(fileName, width, height)


crawlImages('E:\\music')
```

Comment: This solution will throw an exception if there are any non-images in the directory structure.

Comment: Works like a charm now.

Comment: @BrainCity  thank you ..You saved the day. Really appreciate :-)